# MJML - Add a image with specific width for Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, email-templates, mjml, litmus

right now I'm trying to create an email template with MJML. I'm testing the results with litmus and so far the template is perfect for every email client. But

Outlook 365 - on Windows
Outlook 2019 - on Windows

are just stretching the image to 100% width. i searched the whole day for an fix and tried pretty much everything but without success.

this is what I tried to achieve:
[image: Image from template]

here is my MJML code: https://mjml.io/try-it-live/MWzVEfROGFy

this is how it looks on almost every client and here on Outlook 365 on Mac [image: Outlook on Mac but also on every other client]

this is how it looks on Office 365 on Windows

[image: Email on Outlook 365 and Outlook 2019 only on Windows]

in the code you see my try to hide the image on Outlook, that would be a workaround if nothing else is working.

had someone the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you just use an IMG with src="URL" instead of a base64 string it's working.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed the same... For me the image is stretched in height but not width when using base64, but using a URL to point to the image works fine. I don't want to add URL's though... Did you ever find a solution?